# How do I find a 50Hz sin/cos signal in a measurement among other frequencies and noise?

Tags: filters, noise, frequency

I measure magnetic fields with high precision, in a gradiometer setup with fluxgate magnetometers, sampling at 2000Hz. I can have big data sets if I want to - one is 600000+ samples long. I need to find the **phase and amplitude of a 50Hz sine** signal. However there are other (low frequency - 2.145Hz) **stronger signals superimposed**, along with **noise**. Because of those low frequency signals the **DC offset** is hard to eliminate, too. As a result, an FFT gives no results yet.

Now it occured to me that it might be easier to find the 50Hz signal I look for (which is **several orders of magnitude smaller** then the DC offset and the other 2.1Hz signal) and determine its phase and amplitude, in stead of filtering out the rest.

What are good approaches and **algorithms** for that? I code this in python.

edit: here is my python (with numpy) code for my carlos loop algorithm.

```
   def decode_with_carlos_loop(self, frequency, periods_num):
        offsetfree_data = self.file_data
        shape = offsetfree_data.shape
        sampling_freq = 2000

        chunk_size = int(sampling_freq/frequency)
        alpha_step = .075
        indices = np.arange(chunk_size)

        for sensor_cnt in range(0, 4):
            for axis_cnt in range(1,3):
                error_sin = error_cos = 0
                cos_lo = sin_lo = []
                theta_last = 0
                theta = np.zeros(int(shape[1] / chunk_size) + 1)

                for chunk_cnt, chunk_pointer in enumerate(range(0,shape[1],chunk_size)):
                    chunk = offsetfree_data[sensor_cnt, chunk_pointer:chunk_pointer+chunk_size, axis_cnt]

                    cos_lo = np.cos(2*np.pi*frequency*indices/sampling_freq + theta[chunk_cnt])
                    sin_lo = np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*indices/sampling_freq + theta[chunk_cnt])

                    # mean is the lowpass filter
                    error_sin = np.mean(np.multiply(chunk, sin_lo))
                    error_cos = np.mean(np.multiply(chunk, cos_lo))
                    error = error_cos*error_sin
                    theta_last = theta[chunk_cnt+1] = theta[chunk_cnt] - alpha_step*error
                print("sensor:axis:" + str(sensor_cnt) + ":" + str(axis_cnt) + "\tlast theta: " + str((theta_last + np.pi) % (2 * np.pi) - np.pi) + "\tcos_lo: " + str(cos_lo[0]) + "\tsin_lo: " + str(sin_lo[0]) )
```

Comment: Is the signal completely buried in the noise? Can you determine the signal to noise ratio or include a plot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Are any of the signal components synchronized to the sample clock?

Comment: “As a result, an FFT gives no results yet.” That sounds dubious, this problem is exactly what FT should _excel_ at right of the box, nothing else needed. (Assuming it really is a perfect 50 Hz you're talking about, and it's a perfect linear superposition.) What window function have you been using?

Comment: FFT should work.  I've used it to extract signal from very noisy sources.

Comment: Are you able to change/augment the measurement hardware? This sounds like exactly the problem a lock-in amplifier solves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try tracking Phase-frequency of your $50 Hz$ signal using Costas Loop. Costas loop does not require the signal to be pre-processed in order to expose the desired frequency.

I am not giving details of a Costas Loop because it can be found anywhere.It is pretty popular Carrier Recovery technique and a good starting point would be Wikipedia: [CostasLoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costas_loop)

Instead, I would like to tell why I have chosen Costas Loop over other more common Squared-Diffrence Loop and Phase-Locked Loop :

1. Squared-Difference Loop and PLL requires the signal to be pre-processed by a squaring non-linearity and Band-Pass filtering at $f_{center} = 2*f_c$. This is done to emphasize the desired frequency component. This preprocessing step is not required for Costas Loop.
2. Phase Error sensitivity of Costas Loop is approximately double compared to PLL and Squared-Difference Loop. So, even smaller phase offsets in desired Frequencies are more accurately locked onto.
3. There is only Low-Pass filtering required in Costas Loop which can be implemented pretty easily as a Moving Average implementation. As DC-Offset and other low frequency noise is very high which is leaving FFT technique not useful, you can use a low cutoff LPF of enough taps to get a sharp transition, in order to get accurate and almost noise free Error signal $cos(2(\phi - \theta))$.

I have the MATLAB code implemented and customized for your situation at below path:

[CostasLoopPhaseRecovery](https://github.com/SiddhantRaman/DSP_StackExchange/blob/master/CostasCarrierRecovery.m)

The MATLAB Code runs n_runs number of Monty-carlo simulations to show that the algorithm will converge to the true phase of desired frequency eventually.

There are few design parameters which will depend on scenario to scenario. Like, in your case since there is a Large DC offset and a very low frequency component of large magnitude, therefore, you will have to use a good Low-Pass Filter to filter out the Phase Difference signal $cos(2(\phi - \theta))$. I have used a Moving Average Filter for the purpose of Low-Pass Filtering, and so I had to increase the length of filter and increase step size $\alpha$ in order to get phase convergence accurate and faster.

You will see a plot of Phase Convergence looking like below:

[image: CostasLoopPhaseConvergence]

The MATLAB code assumes a DC Offset muchlarger in magnitude than the desired signal component amplitude. I have added $\phi = 0.2$ in the desired signal and the Costas Phase recovery Loop converges to $\phi = 0.2$. There is an inherent ambiguity in phase recovery of $\hat{\phi} = \theta + n\pi$, which appears in the plot too, and it depends on the initial phase of the desired frequency which locally generated and multiplied to the incoming signal.

***Amplitude Estimation:***

Once you have a pretty good estimate of the phase $\phi$ of the sinusoid at frequency $50Hz$ you can generate a reference signal $x[n] = cos(2\pi. 50.nT_s + \hat{\phi}), \forall n \in \{ 0,1,2,3, \cdots , N-1\}$, where A is the parameter to be estimated. You can now use Least Squares technique to estimate the Amplitude as follows:
$$\hat{A} = \frac{1}{N} <x,y>$$
where, $<x,y>$ denotes inner product. The problem is that in doing so we have ignored the fact that our Noise is not uncorrelated (or White) but colored. So, this might result into very wrong estimates. The way to fix the estimation is by generating reference for whatever known frequencies are there in your signal and estimating Amplitude of them, and modeling other unknown frequencies as Colored Noise.

So, in your case, you know that there is large DC offset in your signal and some small frequency component around $2.5Hz$. Assume DC, $2.5Hz$Sinusoid and $50Hz$Sinusoid amplitude as $A_o, A_{2.5} and A_{50}$. Let $y[n]$ be the measured signal, and then you can model $y[n]$ signal as : $$A_o.cos(2\pi 0.nT_s) + A_{2.5}cos(2\pi 2.5nT_s) + A_{50}cos(2\pi 50 nT_s + \hat{\phi}) + w(nT_s),$$where $w(nTs)$ is sampled colored noise (meaning Correlated).

In Matrix Form it would be:
$$\begin{pmatrix} y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} cos(2\pi 0.0T_s) & cos(2\pi 2.5.0T_s) & cos(2\pi 50.0T_s + \hat{\phi})\\ cos(2\pi 0.1T_s) & cos(2\pi 2.5.1T_s) & cos(2\pi 50.1T_s + \hat{\phi}) \\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\cos(2\pi 0.N-1T_s) & cos(2\pi 2.5.N-1T_s) & cos(2\pi 50.N-1T_s + \hat{\phi})\end{pmatrix}. \begin{pmatrix}A_0\\A_{2.5}\\A_{50} \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} w \end{pmatrix}$$ $$y = S.A+w$$
Then the LS solution would be the following:

$$\hat{A} = (S^HS)^{-1}S^H.y$$You can see that the noise is ignored again even though it is colored. The way to fix this is by estimating the Noise Covariance matrix and decolorising the noise or Whitening the noise, and then applying LS Technique.

You can also read about MAFI Algorithm to estimate Amplitudes of known Sinusoids in Colored Noise. That I hope will help you definitely. MAFI runs pretty close to Cramer-Rao Bound even at Low SNRs.

Comment: He needs to acquire the phase of that known sinusoid too. That is why I have suggested a phase recovery Loop. It will be easier to converge to the true phase of desired frequency using a Phase recovery Loop.

Comment: @DanBoschen Phase recovery using Costas Loop is better because it provides better sensitivity compared to a Squared-Difference Loop or a Phase-Locked Loop. For Squared-Difference Loop or PLL to work at similar sensitivity, the system is required to pre-process the incoming received signal in order to emphasize the phase diference sinusoid. If you use Costas-Loop for phase recovery, you get almost double the sensitivity compared to PLL.

Comment: @DanBoschen It is not necessary that you use a Costas Loop only to recover a Carrier Frequency. It can very well be used to recover phase of a know frequency Component, like I have shown. And, in cases when noise is high, Costas Loop is indeed advantageous to use.

Comment: Your implementation does not look like a Costas loop to me but a standard PLL with a phase detector, am I wrong?

Comment: Difference between Costas Loop and a PLL is that, in Costas Loop we first have a phase detector, then Low-pass filtering and then squaring as opposed to PLL where we donot have squaring and hence the sensitivity factor. So, if you see the update equation I have used in implementation is : theta(k+1) = theta(k) - alpha_step*(mean(r_n(avg_len*k-avg_len+1:avg_len*k).*cos_lo).*mean(r_n(avg_len*k-avg_len+1:avg_len*k).*sin_lo)); which will be obtained in case of Costas Loop Error Function Gradient Descent.

Comment: And, the Error function I have used for Gradient Descent is : J_Costas(k+1) = mean(lowpass((r_n(avg_len*k-avg_len+1:avg_len*k).*cos_lo), 0.1).^2); which is exactly as explained in above comment.

Comment: Yes I see now, and how it still locks--- cool! Good to know, thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @jithin time-varying phase would mean a frequency offset, and the above implementation will result in tracking a ramp (if $\phi(t) = \beta t + c$) instead of a constant line, so it will never converge. For time-varying phase, we need Frequency tracking loop, the one which I have implemented is Phase tracking Loop.

Comment: @DanBoschen Even I cannot see his comment now. But, yes we would need a second order PLL to track a ramping phase.

Comment: @DanBoschen I have always understood a 2nd Order digital PLL as two PLLs operating, with output of first PLL being added to output of 2nd PLL before second PLL generates the reference sinusoid for phase difference. So, basically, first PLL will correctly track a ramp : $\theta_{1}(t) = \beta t + c$ and this will be fed to 2nd PLL, which will then be able to track the frequency and phase both correctly. Basically, $\theta_{2}(t) = \phi - c$. So, a sinusoid at Carrier frequency $f_c$ and phase $\phi_1(t) + \theta_2(t)$ will be same as original carrier signal with a phase $\phi(t) = \beta t + c$

Comment: @DanBoschen On a second thought, having 2PLLs operating will definitely have 2 integrators, if that is what type-II 2nd order PLL means.

Comment: I deleted it because I thought it was irrelevant to the question! (the OP just wanted to get the phase and amplitude which you have explained in your answer). But good to see the further discussion regarding 2nd order PLL.

Comment: (Am I missing something?)

Comment: @DanBoschen The 2 PLLs are not in cascade actually, but the output $\theta_1[k]$ is added to the feedback $\theta_2[k]$ of the second PLL and the sum is fed to the frequency generator with phase = $\theta_1[k]+\theta_2[k]$. The same frequency generator is used for phase difference of both the PLLs. This is in context with digital PLL to track constant frequency offset and a phase offset in carrier frequency, which is equivalent to having a ramped phase offset.

Comment: @DSP Thanks! That's a useful answer so I'm going to add that as a question now (and then delete these comments that aren't really related to your answer directly ) if you answer it I will select it

Comment: @DanBoschen The first PLL converges to a line of constant slope equal to the slope of phase ramp, which in turn makes it possible for the second PLL to converge to a constant value. The output sinusoid of second PLL tracks the frequency ($f_c + \beta /2\pi$) of actual carrier very closely.

Comment: @DanBoschen Sure, I will add diagrams and plots to give more details which is not possible in comments. :)

Comment: @DSP Perfect - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66486/2nd-order-type-2-pll-for-tracking-frequency-error

Comment: I do need the amplitude of the signal as well as the phase. is there a clever way to retrieve that, too?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei I am adding a set of steps you can do to figure the amplitude of Sinusoid in a given signal once you have estimated the $\phi$ pretty closely.

Comment: great, thanks. (it is 2.145Hz, not 2.5Hz, but whatever)

Comment: @DSPRookie in the matlab code that you linked I see that you have an avg_len of 1000 and 5000 samples per second. As a lowpass filter you calculate mean() over 1000 samples. Could you please elaborate on your choice of avg_len in relation to the carrier frequency of 50 Hz (100 sample per periode) and the sampling frequency of 5kHz? Is the lowpass filter length (1000) a multiple of the carrier sample count (100) on purpose? 
alpha_step is a dampening factor, right? Can you please speak to its choice, too?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the 50Hz (from the grid) are not constant, but are just close to 50Hz, and change a lot. (https://www.netzfrequenzmessung.de/verlauf.htm ) As far as i understand the costas loop is well suited to follow and compensate that. 

How do I need to adjust your code to compensate for a varing carrier frequency?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei please check my answer to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66486/2nd-order-type-2-pll-for-tracking-frequency-error . This will tell you how to track frequency error between your locally generated sinusoid and the received samples frequency. This will basically keep tracking the frequency error in received signal with respect to the locally generated sinusoid. Reagradin you question of how to choose different params in the algorithm: increasing Moving-Average length will have better Low-pass filtering effect but requires longer delay.

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei contd, Higher $\alpha$ value allows the algo to converge faster to true frequency but is prone to the problem of never converging to the minima of cost function $J$, because minima could be too narrow for the step size to fall into. Also, the Moving average filter size now has to be smaller than the rate of change of frequency of the target sinusoid. If not then, you would be averaging over changing frequency and that will introduce some error into your estimation.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the FFT over that many samples does not show any results, your challenge may be in the overall spectral purity of the 50 Hz tone you seek. The FFT bin at 50 Hz is a correlation to that bin frequency which is the optimum detection in terms of SNR of a 50 Hz signal in the presence of white noise. The issue is the equivalent noise bandwidth of that bin is $1/T$ where $T$ is the total time duration of your signal. So if the energy of the signal you look for is wandering over several bins, then you will have reduced energy in each bin. Ultimately the spectral density of the signal you are looking for needs to be higher than the spectral density of the noise at whatever frequency you are searching in. If you don't see anything with the FFT it suggests that is not the case.

For non-stationary signals (such as the phase noise on a signal of interest at a specific tone) there is an optimum averaging time that will maximize the achievable SNR for the signal-- if your FFT is longer than this averaging time then your result will be degraded. With PLL approaches this same effect goes into choosing the tracking loop bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that comes to mind is to use a Hilbert filter. The lower frequency region needs to be tweaked in order to remove the offending 2.145Hz. Our power metering reference design example should help you get started, but you need to [download the tool](http://www.advsolned.com/asn_filter_designer/) first.

I ran a quick test in the tool, and achieved the following:

[image]

Comment: are you trying to sell your product here?

Comment: Is that all you have to say? I would be a little more grateful that someone has taken timeout to answer your question.

Comment: it was just a question to start with. i would need to download a tool, you dont specify how i would go about using it, and searching for "hilbert filter" left me guessing what it does. The website you link to does not explain it either. To me, it truely feels as if you wanted to place that link, most of all. If you actually tried to help, you didnt put a lot of effort into conveying your approach and much more into presentation and linking. Perhaps you could expand a little on your idea and the hilbert filter to balance that out.